# Не подключается к бд через jdbc на android ниже 5.0

Tags: java, android, jdbc

Не подключается к бд через jdbc на android ниже 5.0. На 5ах, 6ах все работает. Бд mysql. Вот код:

```
 try {
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxx:3306/xxxxxxxx", getString(R.string.login), getString(R.string.pasword));
   Statement st = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM smm");
   while (rs.next()) {
      l = new Integer(rs.getInt(1));
   }

   Log.i(TAG,"dbtest-1" +String.valueOf(l));
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Много что переробовал, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: И никакой ошибки не выдаёт?.. В таком случае сделать ничего практически нельзя.

Comment: Выдает ошибку позже, когда сравнивает полученное значение с другой переменной. Просто ничего не получает с бд. Интересно то ,что у нормальных людей и с 3.0 jdbc работает.

Comment: Я лично с этим не работал, но, вообще, если БД на сервере, то не лучше ли будет забирать с неё данные через php скрипт какой-нить? А то вот пропишите вы в приложении лог-пасс к базе а его кто-нить с маркета декомпилирует и потрёт вам БД...

Comment: попробуйте не юзать `ThreadPolicy`, а вынести обращение к БД в отдельный поток

Comment: Пробовал убрать threadpolycy и в отдельный поток, не робит.